# Building a Custom Library of Ruby, JS, and CSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

What is the best approach to abstract out a library from your application that you would like to include in another application. Right now, the code is scattered through the app:

```
app/assets
app/models
app/controllers
app/views
```

Is it a best practice to move them to the lib? Like this:

```
lib/yaffle/assets
lib/yaffle/models
lib/yaffle/controllers
lib/yaffle/views
```

Or is this when you should create a [plugin](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html)?

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't know about "the best approach", but I tend to create gems for code that I want to reuse across applications.

Comment: Here is the guidance - please check Rails Engines: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html I think this is what you need

Comment: @IlyaKonyukhov post that as an answer so I can accept it! I think that is exactly what I need!

Comment: Done :) It's easier to learn Rails Engines by example I think. So here they are: https://medium.com/ruby-on-rails/patterns-for-successful-rails-engines-a7dae3db6921 It helped me some time ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the guidance - please check [Rails Engines](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html). I think this is what you need :)